# Bootstrap horizontal navbar is breaking down in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="top">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active"><a href="index.php"><i class="icon-white"></i>Home </a></li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><i class=""></i>
                Apartments<span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href='acacia.php'><span>Acacia</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='bluebell.php'><span>Bluebell</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='rose.php'><span>Rose</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='orchid.php'><span>Orchid</span></a></li>
        <li class='last'><a href='waratah.php'><span>Waratah</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="map.php"><i  class="icon-white"></i>Location & Environment</a></li>
    <li><a href="plans.php"><i class="icon-white"></i>Plans  & Layouts</a></li>
    <li><a href="aboutus.php"><i class="icon-white"></i>Developers</a></li>
    <li><a href="interior.php"><i  class="icon-white"></i>Interior</a></li>
    <li><a href="contactus.php"><i  class="icon-white"></i>Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I created a horizontal top nav bar using this code and it worked fine in my localhost for IE, Firefox, Chrome. It is not working in IE when I uploaded it to a free hosting server. The horizontal navbar is breaking down and becoming a vertical navbar. It's working on other browsers correctly.

Comment: Which IE version are you testing? Remember that Bootstrap supports only a few of the newest version (IE9+, IIRC).

Comment: What is your IE version?

Comment: IE8. :( . do i have any work around?

Comment: but why is then it is working on my localhost server???

Comment: Have you read the Bootstrap support ? http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support

Comment: no! will it solve my problem?

Comment: Lol ! When I read it, it's written : "Internet Explorer 8 and 9 : Internet Explorer 8 and 9 are also supported, however, please be aware that some... etc blablabla" ... So... RTFM

Answer (score 1):

You can use JS to fix for IE8-. Like this:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using bootstrap 3 then it does not have support for ie below version 8 .
Few points you have to keep in mind for using bootstrap and for avoiding break down in ie:

1> Check if there is not any html tag or div which is unclosed.

2> Add respond.js for media queries to be working in IE.

3> Add html5shiv if you are using html5 tags.

Comment: can you show me an example of how to add this. i mean the code. thanksx in advance.

Comment: check bootstraps official site http://getbootstrap.com/.Hit ctrl U check its source code u will get ur answer.